# Clear fields on postback/errors - MVC with DataType attribute validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model, webforms

On my `ResetPassword` action I am trying to clear the email and password fields on post-backs such as when an error occurs. I have tried to use `ModelState.Clear()`, however the issue is that certain errors never post back to the action

such as:

> "The Password must be at least 6 characters long."
>
> "The password and confirmation password do not match."

I believe the reason for this is due to  `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` and/or the model `DataType` attributes

The **ResetPassword** view is as follows:

```
@model TestGame.ViewModels.ResetPasswordViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reset password";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", autocomplete="off" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Reset your password</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Code)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

and the **ResetPasswordViewModel** is as follows:

```
public class ResetPasswordViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to clear the fields. Doing that will be annoying to the users who will be forced to type everything again. But if you still want to do it anyway then keep reading.

The errors that you mentioned not to be posting back are validation errors, which are handled on the client-side. So to clear the fields in this case, you will need some JavaScript code. You will need to do one of the following:

- Write your own JavaScript of the client-side validation and use the custom validation to attach it to your fields.
- Modify the JavaScript of the client-side validation. This is not recommended, but it works.
- Hack the JavaScript of the client-side validation by adding additional JavaScript function that will run right after the validation. Run your page in the browser and view the generated source code then search for the JavaScript validation near the bottom.

Comment: I want to clear the fields because I think certain fields (such as password field) should be cleared on an error for security reasons

Comment: What security benefits do you expect by clearing it? I cannot think of any.